# How to close old PushNotificationChannel in Application?

Tags: c#, push-notification, windows-phone-8.1

I have a huge problem with storing PushNotificationChannel. The type itselt cannot be stored in LocalSettings.

I need it to close the channel after getting new one. I request new channel each time app is started (as documentation says) and sometimes I get new channel (different from previous) while the previous stil works (resulting in duplicate push notifications). So I when I get new channel I want to fore close the old one.

I have also tried serializing it to stream using:

```
var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(PushNotificationChannel));
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
serializer.WriteObject(ms, channel);
```

But I get error:

> 'Windows.Networking.PushNotifications.PushNotificationChannel' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute. Alternatively, you can ensure that the type is public and has a parameterless constructor - all public members of the type will then be serialized, and no attributes will be required.

Is there a way to store PushNotificationChannel or can I store only URI and somehow create Channel object from uri?

EDIT:

Ok I can get Channel in my PushNotificationReceived. But I do not know how to get  sender PushNotificationChannel in my BackgroundTask - is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes yo can get PushNotificationChannel in Background. You need to create background tasks for this and hit API in background task to get push notification channel Uri. For creating background tasks in windows store apps [see this tutorial.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/create-and-register-a-background-task)

Comment: I have BackgroundTask witn PushNotification trigger. But what do you mean by hiting API in background task? I need PushNotificationChannel sender like in event PushNotificationReceived

Comment: Each time you request a new Channel uri can change for it not the handler. So you don't need to close it yourself. You just need to update uri in your database and old one will not work. Also API hitting is part of updating your new Channel Uri on your server.

Comment: Each time Uri changes I remove old one from server and add new - but there few times (once or twice) that did not work - and I ended getting notifications twice (I got new channel but the old one still worked). So I want some way to force close channel (to avoid this error) - It works when application is running but I want this mechanism to work also when only background task is running.

Comment: If that's not possible we'll have to improve out server (of fix removing method if something is not working).

Comment: If you replaced the ChannelUri from server then you should not have old one. If you received two notifications then either you have Uri stored at multiple places, which should be updated. Also it can be that you might have sent the notification twice because to send notification you need to create it dynamically.

Comment: jakubWisniewski @Rohit  Can you please see this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43122189/onesignal-push-notification-clickevent-show-empty-values-windows-phone-8-1-c-sha